# Is it possible to use 2 factory functions to populate 1 instance?

Tags: javascript, factory-pattern

Using a single [factory function](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#factorypatternjavascript) to populate an instance is straightforward.  In the example below I use the factory function `aircraftFactory()` to create a new instance called `supermarine`.  However I'm not sure how to structure this so that both `aircraftFactory()` and `engines()` could be used together to create `supermarine`.

```js
"use strict"

function aircraftFactory(x) {
    return {
        manufacturer: x.manufacturer,
        factory: x.factory
    }
}

function engines(x) {
    return {
        numberOfEngines: x.numberOfEngines,
        costPerEngine: x.costPerEngine
    }
}

let supermarine = aircraftFactory({manufacturer: 'Supermarine', factory: 'Southampton'});

document.querySelector('.output').textContent = supermarine.manufacturer;
```

```html
<div class='output'></div>
```

I tried chaining them together like this but it threw an error.

*Uncaught TypeError: aircraftFactory(...).engines is not a function*

```js
let supermarine = aircraftFactory({manufacturer: 'Supermarine', factory: 'Southampton'}).engines({numberOfEngines: 1, costPerEngine: 35000});
```

I know there must be a pattern but I can't find an example or figure it out.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: You want to merge the two objects? you can add properties to JS literal objects just doing obj.property = x; The "dot notation" will try to call a property or method form the object.

Comment: I don't necessarily want to merge the factories.  In some instances I may  want to use 1 and other times both.  So I need to keep them separate and call them as needed.  I know how to add single properties but I'd rather do it with factories.

Comment: That's too unclear, why and when you would decide it? On creation?

Comment: Yes when I create the instance sometimes I may want to use 1 factory function, other times I may want to call multiple factory functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extend `engines` to `aircraftFactory` you need to use `prototype`

> **Prototypes** extends/inherit your properties and methods.

Try this

```
"use strict"

function aircraftFactory(x) {
  this.manufacturer = x.manufacturer;
  this.factory = x.factory;
}

function engines(x) {
    return {
        numberOfEngines: x.numberOfEngines,
        costPerEngine: x.costPerEngine
    }
}

//This is where you extend engines
aircraftFactory.prototype.engines = engines;

//Create the instance of aircraftFactory
let supermarine = new aircraftFactory({manufacturer: 'Supermarine', factory: 'Southampton'}).engines({numberOfEngines: 1, costPerEngine: 35000});
```

Comment: Is there a way to encapsulate that into 1 instance instead of both supermarine and test?

Comment: Very interesting.  Your example used a constructor.  It's not possible with a factory function?

Comment: nope you can't,  prototype needs `new` and `constructor`

Answer (score 2):

I think I have a suggestion for you:

```
function engines(x) {
    return {
        numberOfEngines: x.numberOfEngines,
        costPerEngine: x.costPerEngine
    }
}
```

If you pass an engine:

```
function aircraftFactory(x, engine) {
    let aircraft = {
        manufacturer: x.manufacturer,
        factory: x.factory
    };

    if (engine) {
      aircraft.numberOfEngines = engine.numberOfEngines;
      aircraft.costPerEngine = engine.costPerEngine;
    }

    return aircraft;
}
```

You could create an instance like this:

```
let aircraft = aicraftFactory(x, engineFactory(y));
```

But if you want to create the properties without knowing the names:

```
function aircraftFactory(x, extended) {
    let aircraft = {
        manufacturer: x.manufacturer,
        factory: x.factory
    };

    if (engine) {
        for (let key in extended) {
            aircraft[key] = extended[key];
        }
    }

    return aircraft;
}
```